# Why does jQuery throw the error `fadeOut is not a function'?

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery and put this code in my javascript:

```
function HideMe(itemID) {
    var myDiv = 'item_' + itemID;
    $(myDiv).fadeOut("slow");
}
```

But its giving me this error: *`fadeOut` is not a function*.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Do you have another javascript library on that page? It seems you have the `hide` function, and the `$` defined (prototype, for example, also has an `hide` function).
If that is the case, try:

```
jQuery("#item_0").fadeOut("slow");
```

Comment: Mostly the "another javascript library" is the slim version of jQuery itself which does not include animation effects.

Comment: @SunilKumar - The [slim version was release in 2016](https://blog.jquery.com/2016/09/22/jquery-3-1-1-released/) - 7 years after this answer! 

Comment: @Kobi That doesn't mean it isn't a reason why people are still arriving at this page. Sunil's comment helped me.

Comment: @Martin - Sure! It's a good thing there's also another answer that explains that, so we don't need to answer this one.

Answer (score 169):

This will happen if you're using the "slim" version of jQuery.  Only the "full" version of jQuery includes animation effects.

Try grabbing the "full" version of jQuery from the [jQuery downloads page](https://jquery.com/download/) and including that in your page (or including a full version of [jQuery from a CDN](https://code.jquery.com/) from your page).

Comment: I can't believe it was that stupid problem..... such waste of time for minor problem............. Thanks man !

Comment: Slim is included in bootstrap CDN: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/

Answer (score 21):

I had this error because I was using a slim version of jQuery. If you download the full version you should be okay.

Answer (score 4):

**Even if the selector didn't return any items in the collection the function call would have worked (*not generated this error anyway*) if jQuery was loaded correctly.** Either there is a conflict in the page, or it didn't load at all. You can try

```
jQuery(myDiv).fadeOut("slow");
```

or look into why jQuery hasn't been loaded.

P.S.: don't forget the `#` in the selector if selecting by id.

Comment: How can i check that jQuery is loaded or not. I am able to use $(myDiv).hide(); function perfectly. but not fadeOut

Answer (score 4):

It happened to me because of slim version of Jquery library. Full version of Jquery library includes animation.

Jquery CDN available at https://code.jquery.com/

Answer (score 3):

Also, you probably forgot a `#` in the selector (unless you've got something like `<item_1 />` in the markup).

```
var myDiv = '#item_' + itemID;
```

jQuery uses CSS selectors to search for elements, so without the `#`, you'd get every element with the tag `item_x` instead of the ID.

Comment: Doesn't matter though, this error doesn't pop up if jQuery is loaded correctly.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I just posted this if it *still* didn't work. I thought the variable naming was the problem, though I now see I was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like jquery is not correctly attached to the page.

Check your linking to jQuery.

Comment: It's attached because I am able to use $(myDiv).hide(); function perfectly

Comment: You are linking to jQuery in the Head section? Are you using another javascript library that also uses the $ character as an identifier? ( OpenLayers is one such library)

Answer (score 2):

Try keeping it inside

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// your code. and don't forget the '#' in front of item.
});
```

Looks like you're trying to call the function before jQuery / the DOM loads.

Comment: when i use $(document).ready(function() { } its saying $(document).ready is not a function

Answer (score 1):

You have `liDiv` instead of `myDiv`. Try:

```
function HideMe(itemID) {
    var myDiv = 'item_' + itemID;
    $(myDiv).fadeOut("slow");
}
```

Comment: my mistake .....i used myDiv, but it was written wrong here, its not working using myDiv though.

Answer (score 0):

On moving a .html template to a wordpress one, I found this popping up regularly.

Two reasons, and the console error can be deceptive:

1. The error in the console can **send you down the wrong path**. It MIGHT not be the real issue. First reason for me was the **order** in which you have set your .js files to load. In html easy, put them in the same order as the theme template. In Wordpress, you need to enqueue them in the right order, but also set a priority if they don't appear in the right order,
2. Second thing is are the .js files in the **header or the footer**. Moving them to the footer can solve the issue - it did for me, after a day of trying to debug the issue. Usually doesn't matter, but for a complex page with lots of js libraries, it might!