# fadeOut() isn't working ? Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to fade element out using jquery ....  no luck

HTML element I'm struggling to fade out:

```
<div class="alert alert-success" id='success' style='margin-top: 
20px;width:320px;' role="alert"><strong>Done.</strong><br>
    Comment updated.</div>
```

Jquery bit:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#success').click(function() {
       $(this).fadeOut();
   });
});
</script>
```

and I'm using this cdn to pull Jquery from Jquery servers:

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js"
integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n"
 crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Any idea why this is not working ?

Comment: what's the error in the console of your browser? Is there any?

Comment: The pasted jQuery bit is invalid JavaScript. You are missing a closing brace on the function that you pass to `click`.

Comment: You're using jquery slim, which doesnt support animations.

Comment: I admit I completely forgotten about the console. It says `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`.

Comment: I thought Jquery uses dollar sign.

Comment: In that case I'd ensure you're using the correct cdn, and that you're referencing it in the head of your html.

Comment: is jquery loaded before your script?

Comment: 1) Slim doesn't have animations. 2) Works fine. https://jsfiddle.net/davelnewton/7ckmxy35/

Comment: Yes, it is ... I'll try different cdn link. The one from Google perhaps.

Comment: Yeah folks .... It was the wrong cdn link. I pasted in the proper one without that "slim" thingy in it and it works ..

Comment: @Dave Newton   If you post your answer as suggested answer I'll nike it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @ManuelOtto mentioned [jQuery slim library does not include fadeOut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934446/why-does-jquery-throw-the-error-fadeout-is-not-a-function).  I was able to get your code to work with the following library

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

[jsbin](https://jsbin.com/roroqovisu/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: You share credit with @Dave Newton. You three can have a beer on me.  :)

Comment: @MarkyMark deal!