# JavaScript doesn't work with bootstrap 4 + thymeleaf

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-boot, bootstrap-4, thymeleaf

I'm developing a web app with Spring Boot, Bootstrap 4 and Thymeleaf. 
I want to show a bootstrap alert, and then, it hides automatically after seconds (just like a "sucessfully" notification).

I have found a lot of solutions, but all of then need JavaScript. When I tried to use JS on my project, it doesn't work.

I use a default template, which is used in the others views through `layout:decorate="~{default}"`. In this default template, I have the Bootstrap link and scripts:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

...

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

If a put in any view the following code, it does nothing.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
 xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout" layout:decorate="~{default}">

    <head>
      ...
    </head>

    <body class="text-center">
        <div layout:fragment="content">

            <div class="product-options">
                <a id="myWish" href="javascript:;" class="btn btn-mini">Add to Wishlist </a>
                <a href="" class="btn btn-mini"> Purchase </a>
            </div>
            <div class="alert alert-success" id="success-alert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
                <strong>Success! </strong> Product have added to your wishlist.
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#success-alert").hide();
                    $("#myWish").click(function showAlert() {
                        $("#success-alert").fadeTo(2000, 500)
                        .slideUp(500, function () {
                            $("#successalert").slideUp(500);
                        });
                    });
                });
            </script>
            ...

        </div>
    </body>
```

NOTE: This is just an example to check that JS doesn't work. I takes it from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23101966/bootstrap-alert-auto-close).

When I run this code, the alert is showed, but it never disappears. I have tried with a lot of scripts and never work.

Could be a compatibility version problem?

Comment: in thymeleaf write  <script th:inline="javascript"></script> instade of <script type="text/javascript"><script> tag

Comment: Thanks a lot @Atanu, I had to add th:line in order to run it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I think this post address your problem:

[Why does jQuery throw the error `fadeOut is not a function'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934446/why-does-jquery-throw-the-error-fadeout-is-not-a-function)

In this line `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>` you use the slim version of Jquery not the full-one, this prompt when I click to "Add to Wishlist" link" a TypeError in the Firefox develloper tool console.

`TypeError: $(...).fadeTo is not a function`, this means that the Jquery javascript object `$("#success-alert")` doesn't have attached a `fadeTo` function.

You can get the full minified version here: https://code.jquery.com/

Snippet from https://code.jquery.com

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

PS: If you don't need [SRI](https://www.w3.org/TR/SRI/) you can remove `integrity` and `crossorigin` attributes.

Comment: Thank you. That was the problem. I just need to change to the full version of jquery and it works perfectly.

Comment: I was wondering why a lot of answers involving jquery weren't working for me. Thanks, this let me use a lot of answers I couldn't before.