# Text dont fade in/out, What could be the Problem?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Fixed !! i needed to use the full Core of Jquery not the slim version

I overlaped two div containers. Now at site load i wanna hide the one div and if i enter the second div(caption in this case) this caption should fade out and the first div(the main text) should be fade in. 
I can hide it at start but in non case it plays any fade animation.

I tried every (me known) text container inside the div like h1(for the caption), span and p. None of them work :(

```css
#navbar-header a {
    font-size: 20px;
}

#navbar-header {
    padding-right: 30px;
}

body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

.dropdown-item {
    font-size: 15px !important;
}

.navbar {
    opacity: 0.7 !important;
}

footer {
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 0.7 !important;
}

#welcomeHead{
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 300px;
    font-family: 'Varela Round';
    font-size: 3rem;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 3rem;
    letter-spacing: .8rem;
    color: #000000;
}
#welcomeBody{
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 200px;
    font-family: 'Varela Round';
    font-size: 2rem;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 3rem;
    color: #000000 !important;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script>$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#welcomeBody").hide();
        $("#welcomeHead").mouseenter(function () { 
        $("#welcomeHead").fadeOut();
        });
        });</script>
</head>

<body id="bootstrap-overrides">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="damnik_logo.png" width="100" height="100" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="logo">
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown"
            aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" id="navbar-header">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button"
                        data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Aufgaben
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" id="test" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">HTML Brief</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Erste Website</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CSS</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Tabellen</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">JavaScript</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Raster Layout</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Bootstrap</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Bericht</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Kontakt</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div>
        <span class="mx-auto my-0 text-uppercase" id="welcomeHead">Willkommen auf meiner Seite</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="text-white-50 mx-auto mt-2 mb-5" id="welcomeBody"> Auf dieser Seite wird ihnen mein Portfolio, mit
            allen
            bisher erfüllten Aufgaben bereigestellt.
            Diese finden sie unter dem Punkt Aufgaben.<br>
            Unter Bericht steht ihnen der gesamte Werdegang dieser Seite anschaulich zur Verfügung.<br>
            Infos zu meiner Person und meinem persöhnlichen Werdegang finden sie unter About.<br>
            Falls es nach dies allem noch Fragen, Wünsche oder Anmerkungen gibt können sie mich unter
            Kontakt jederzeit per Mail kontaktieren.<br>
            Viel Spaß auf meiner Seite.</span>
    </div>
    <footer class="page-footer font-small cyan darken-3 fixed-bottom">
        <!-- Quelle:https://mdbootstrap.com/education/bootstrap/ -->
        <div class="footer-copyright text-center py-3">
            <img src="damnik_logo.png" width="25" height="25" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="logo">
            © 2019 Copyright: Marvin Damnik
            <a href="#">Impressum</a>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

ok here on stack overflow i see that i runs me an error message that fadeOut isnt a method. But in this case more Question marks appears over my Head. 
It isnt a valid Method from jquery ? Jquery is in my meaning inlcuded with Bootstrap in this project o.O

Fixed. Over 12 Hours Ago i started with this project and was confused if the slim version will make problems, now i dont recognize this anymore and waste over 1 hour to fix this problem... Thanks all

Comment: look at F12 and see the error! :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934446/why-does-jquery-throw-the-error-fadeout-is-not-a-function

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery throw the error \`fadeOut is not a function'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934446/why-does-jquery-throw-the-error-fadeout-is-not-a-function)

Comment: you are using jQuery  slim that don't have the fadeout option, try to use this jquery version <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You can add an answer to your question and accept it, so that if someone finds this they also have a clear answer

Answer (score 0):

Include jQuery Core. You can find the difference between slim and core version [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424053/what-are-the-differences-between-normal-and-slim-package-of-jquery).

In short the effects like `fadeOut` are not available in the slim version, which was causing the issue.

```css
#navbar-header a {
  font-size: 20px;
}

#navbar-header {
  padding-right: 30px;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.dropdown-item {
  font-size: 15px !important;
}

.navbar {
  opacity: 0.7 !important;
}

footer {
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.7 !important;
}

#welcomeHead {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 300px;
  font-family: 'Varela Round';
  font-size: 3rem;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 3rem;
  letter-spacing: .8rem;
  color: #000000;
}

#welcomeBody {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 200px;
  font-family: 'Varela Round';
  font-size: 2rem;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 3rem;
  color: #000000 !important;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#welcomeBody").hide();
      $("#welcomeHead").mouseenter(function() {
        $("#welcomeHead").fadeOut();
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body id="bootstrap-overrides">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="damnik_logo.png" width="100" height="100" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="logo">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" id="navbar-header">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Aufgaben
                    </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" id="test" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">HTML Brief</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Erste Website</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CSS</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Tabellen</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">JavaScript</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Raster Layout</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Bootstrap</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Bericht</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Kontakt</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div>
    <span class="mx-auto my-0 text-uppercase" id="welcomeHead">Willkommen auf meiner Seite</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <span class="text-white-50 mx-auto mt-2 mb-5" id="welcomeBody"> Auf dieser Seite wird ihnen mein Portfolio, mit
            allen
            bisher erfüllten Aufgaben bereigestellt.
            Diese finden sie unter dem Punkt Aufgaben.<br>
            Unter Bericht steht ihnen der gesamte Werdegang dieser Seite anschaulich zur Verfügung.<br>
            Infos zu meiner Person und meinem persöhnlichen Werdegang finden sie unter About.<br>
            Falls es nach dies allem noch Fragen, Wünsche oder Anmerkungen gibt können sie mich unter
            Kontakt jederzeit per Mail kontaktieren.<br>
            Viel Spaß auf meiner Seite.</span>
  </div>
  <footer class="page-footer font-small cyan darken-3 fixed-bottom">
    <!-- Quelle:https://mdbootstrap.com/education/bootstrap/ -->
    <div class="footer-copyright text-center py-3">
      <img src="damnik_logo.png" width="25" height="25" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="logo"> © 2019 Copyright: Marvin Damnik
      <a href="#">Impressum</a>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of the div in the HTML, because if not the one that should get the mouse event is under the other, so the mouse never touches it.

Also move the `is` to the `div` containers, not to in the `span` inside. So in that way when the div layer disappears the other bellows get the mouse event.

In this example the appear and disappear alternatively.

```css
#navbar-header a {
  font-size: 20px;
}

#navbar-header {
  padding-right: 30px;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.dropdown-item {
  font-size: 15px !important;
}

.navbar {
  opacity: 0.7 !important;
}

footer {
  background-color: white;
  opacity: 0.7 !important;
}

#welcomeHead {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 300px;
  font-family: 'Varela Round';
  font-size: 3rem;
  width: 60%;
  line-height: 3rem;
  letter-spacing: .8rem;
  color: #000000;
  border: solid 1px red;
}

#welcomeBody {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 200px;
  font-family: 'Varela Round';
  font-size: 2rem;
  width: 80%;
  line-height: 3rem;
  color: #000000 !important;
  position: absolute;
  border: dashed 1px green;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#welcomeBody").hide();
      $("#welcomeHead").mouseenter(function() {
        console.log('Body');
        $("#welcomeHead").fadeOut();
        $("#welcomeBody").fadeIn();
      });

      $("#welcomeBody").mouseenter(function() {
        console.log('Head');
        $("#welcomeBody").fadeOut();
        $("#welcomeHead").fadeIn();
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body id="bootstrap-overrides">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light sticky-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="damnik_logo.png" width="100" height="100" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="logo">
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto" id="navbar-header">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        Aufgaben
                    </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" id="test" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">HTML Brief</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Erste Website</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CSS</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Tabellen</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">JavaScript</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Raster Layout</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Bootstrap</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Bericht</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Kontakt</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
   
  <div id="welcomeBody">
    <span class="text-white-50 mx-auto mt-2 mb-5"> Auf dieser Seite wird ihnen mein Portfolio, mit
            allen
            bisher erfüllten Aufgaben bereigestellt.
            Diese finden sie unter dem Punkt Aufgaben.<br>
            Unter Bericht steht ihnen der gesamte Werdegang dieser Seite anschaulich zur Verfügung.<br>
            Infos zu meiner Person und meinem persöhnlichen Werdegang finden sie unter About.<br>
            Falls es nach dies allem noch Fragen, Wünsche oder Anmerkungen gibt können sie mich unter
            Kontakt jederzeit per Mail kontaktieren.<br>
            Viel Spaß auf meiner Seite.</span>
  </div>
  <div id="welcomeHead">
    <span class="mx-auto my-0 text-uppercase">Willkommen auf meiner Seite</span>
  </div>
  <footer class="page-footer font-small cyan darken-3 fixed-bottom">
    <!-- Quelle:https://mdbootstrap.com/education/bootstrap/ -->
    <div class="footer-copyright text-center py-3">
      <img src="damnik_logo.png" width="25" height="25" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="logo"> © 2019 Copyright: Marvin Damnik
      <a href="#">Impressum</a>
    </div>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```