# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fadeOut is not a function

Tags: jquery

I get this error in jQuery:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fadeOut is not a function.

This is my jQuery code:

```
$("div").click(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut(1000);
});
```

Comment: Are you using a subset of the jQuery library that does not have animations bundled in? For example Sizzle?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does jQuery throw the error \`fadeOut is not a function'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934446/why-does-jquery-throw-the-error-fadeout-is-not-a-function)

Comment: I caught the solution of the exception occurred in my code. The problem was in there JQuery library. Library that i use in my code does not contain the animation bundle. So that's why fadeOut is not a function throw by JQuerry. Thanks @Terry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$("#clickme").click(function() {
  $(this).fadeOut("slow", function() {
    console.log('Animation complete.');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="clickme">
  Click here to fade out
</div>
```

Comment: The exception thrown by JQuerry because of JQuerry library which i added does not contain animation bundle. Thanks  for helping me Dibash Sapkota.