# Django how to disappeared bootstrap alert box messages after few seconds

Tags: javascript, django, django-bootstrap3

Before posting this question I found few solutions on stackoverflow and tried but non of them didn't work. I want the message will be disappeared after 2 or three seconds. here is my code:

```
 {% if messages %}
                <ul class="messages">
                    {% for message in messages %}
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                    <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %}>{{ message }}</li>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </ul>
 {% endif %}
```

it look like this:
[image]

here given below few JavaScript code which I tried for disappeared the alert box after few seconds but none of them didn't work:

**code1:**

```
<script text="javascript">
    setTimeout(fade_out, 3000);
    function fade_out() {
        $(".messages").fadeOut().empty();
    }
    
 
</script>
```

**code2**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // messages timeout for 10 sec 
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.message').fadeOut('slow');
        }, 10000); // <-- time in milliseconds, 1000 =  1 sec

        // delete message
        $('.alert').live('click',function(){
            $('.alert').parent().attr('style', 'display:none;');
        })
    });
</script>
```

**code3**

```
<script>
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.messages').fadeOut('fast');
}, 30000); // <-- time in milliseconds
</script>
```

**code4**

```
<script>setTimeout(function(){$('.messages').fadeOut();}, 15000);</script>
```

I am not understanding why above code not working? where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Do you put your javascript at the end of your HTML file or not?

Comment: @Mahdi mehrabi yes I put it on my html file but not understanding why it's not working

Comment: and do you see any error log in inspect element console?

Comment: seeing this error for code1 `(index):267 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fadeOut is not a function
    at fade_out ((index):267)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934446/why-does-jquery-throw-the-error-fadeout-is-not-a-function is this solve your problem?

Comment: Mahdi mehrabi No it's not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code 2 is right just you have a typo in your code use `messages` class instead of `message` class

put this code just before `</body>`

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        // messages timeout for 10 sec
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.messages').fadeOut('slow');
        }, 10000); // <-- time in milliseconds, 1000 =  1 sec
    });
</script>
```

I test this code myself and it works fine

Comment: Mahdi mehrabi I am using bootstrap 4. Do I need to add extranal any javscript cdn or url???

Comment: @boyenec Delete your own jquery and use the jquery cdn  in the answer

Comment: @boyenec and put these codes just before </body>

Comment: yeah it's working and happening  error occurring for previous  javscript  cdn.

Comment: @boyenec I'm glad that your problem solved :) and don't use .live method its decrepted

Comment: @ Mahdi mehrabi okay and Thanks again