# what is wrong with my slideshow code in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am taking an intro to javaScript/jQuery class and have to make a header slide show, I can't get it to work, could you please take a look and see what errors I might have made? I am hitting a dead end and it feels like I'm banging my head against a wall. it says I need to add more typing that isn't code, so i'm typing more here. Please feel free to ask any clarifying questions,

```js
"use strict";
$(document).ready( () => {
    let nextSlide = $("#slides img:first-child");
        
    setInterval( () => {   
        $("#caption").fadeOut(2000);
        $("#slide").fadeOut(2000,
            () => {
                if (nextSlide.next().length == 0) {
                    nextSlide = $("#slides img:first-child");
                }
                else {
                    nextSlide = nextSlide.next();
                }
                const nextSlideSource = nextSlide.attr("src");
                const nextCaption = nextSlide.attr("alt");
                $("#slide").attr("src", nextSlideSource).fadeIn(1000);                    
                $("#caption").text(nextCaption).fadeIn(1000);
            });    // end fadeOut()
    },
    1000);         // end setInterval()
});
```

```css
#slides img {
    display: none;
}
#slide {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>SlideShow</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="slide_show.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Slide SlideShow</h2>
    <header>
        <h2 id="caption">Headers</h2>
        <img id="slide" src="Images/Header/paintingone.jpg" alt="">
        <div id="slides"> 
            <img src="Images/Header/paintingone.jpg" alt="One">
            <img src="Images/Header/paintingtwo.jpg" alt="Two">
            <img src="Images/Header/paintingthree.jpg" alt="Three">
            <img src="Images/Header/paintingfour.jpg" alt="Four">
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>
    
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you run the snippet you'll see the error. `fadeOut is not a function`. This is because you're using the `slim` branch of jQuery, not the full one. The slim branch has features such as AJAX, and importantly in this case, animation, removed. Change the script reference to `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js` and the code works

Comment: In the duplicate I marked, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40155286/519413) is your solution